# VB reset progress bar value after download

Tags: vb.net, image, download, progress

As a bit of practice I am trying to get my program to download a file via the progress bar. It downloads it fine and the progress bar follows but the problem is that after the download is complete it wont reset. This is the code for the button and the bar.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("imageurlhere"), "c:\myfile.jpg")
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WC_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WC.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("imageurlhere"), "c:\myfile.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub WC_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WC.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did'nt work, tried that before (changed place on the reset function)

Comment: Set ProgressBar1.Maximum = 1 (100% value)

Comment: For some reason now it works... ish, the if function does reset the bar but the problem is that the bars green does not manage to get to the end before the if function resets it but that can be solved by shortening the bar I think.

Comment: I don't think so .. May I know your ProgressBar1.Minimum value ?

Comment: It's not set anywhere. The value function only moves it via % of something that I guess would be undefined.

Comment: ProgressBar1.Minimum =0 .. any effect ?

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar activity can be very uncertain, in terms of operating and functioning as intended (as you would think it should behave) in the final behavior on a cancellation of a WebClient.CancelAsync() run of the function that this client is assigned to within the application. I do not have knowledge of having a progress bar reset to the minimum value after a download has completed without being cancelled. So, I will offer two snippets of code that I use to play with, as a design basis that seems to be a "simple" starting point of windows form development / ASP.NET development programming, ' BAREBONES ' versions, WITHOUT USING A BACKGROUND WORKER INSTANCE TO PROCESS THE DOWNLOAD ACTIVITY CHANGES.

1. It seems that a "cancellation" of a current download in progress seems to raise some quirky behavior, as a button click does not quite seem to raise the cancel event properly to cause a "stop" and "reset" interruption to the form on the button click of the cancel button, used with CancelAsync() within the button click event. So, I have seen several variant behaviors, depending on what is assigned to the progress bar properties / methods implemented in the code logic of this event.

So, it seems that I have only a simple workaround of using a MessageBox.Show() interruption or a custom form that serves as the same purpose of the message box form.

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    ' THE Kill() IS NOT NECESSARY IF THE MessageBox Show() is IMPLEMENTED AND USED
    'Kill(TextBox2.Text) ' since the Cancel button does not fully stop the download
    ' and clear the prgress bar to reset that to "0", this is used to stop the download
    ' at the root path of the saved file destinatio !!!!n
    download.CancelAsync()
    ProgressBar1.Disposing.ToString()
    ' ProgressBar1.Dispose() ' hides the progress bar here
    ProgressBar1.Update()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    ProgressBar1.Show()
    LastCount = 0

    ' Label4.ResetText()
    Label4.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
    Label4.Text = "THE FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED .. A - N - D .. ALSO ABORTED !!!!!!!"
    Label4.Visible = True
    ' Label5.ResetText()
    Label5.Text = "NO TRANSFER RATE - FILE DOWNLOAD CANCEL and ABORTED"
    Label5.Visible = True
    'Label6.ResetText()
    Label6.Text = "Saved Copy of File Download is : "
    'Label7.ResetText()
    Label7.Text = "Download Source File Size is : "
    Label8.ResetText()
    Label8.Text = ""
    'Label10.ResetText()
    'Label10.Text += Label10.Text & " was the previous file downloading transfer rate...."


    ' trows error if there is not a file in the directory
    ' IO.File.Delete(savedLocation) ' delete the file in the chosen directory, if present

    cmdsave.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
    'Label4.Visible = True ' to alleviate the text that will be shown as the "old"
    'Label5.Visible = True ' values of the cancelled download, so make these not visible
    ' ...... make the labels "invislbe" now, but make them "visible" when the
    ' ...... cmdsae button is clicked, or see if the form load can make them
    ' ...... visbile again  -->>> POST THE CANCELLATION MESSAGE IN
    ' .....  TEXTBOX1 OR LABEL



    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then

        Label4.ResetText()
        Label4.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Label4.Text = ""
        ' Button1.Enabled = False ' DOES NOT WORK HERE !!
        MessageBox.Show("FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED / ABORTED !!")

        Button1.Enabled = False ' DOES W-O-R-K -- GREAT -- HERE !!
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Update()
        ' ProgressBar1.Hide()
        ' ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        'Label4.ResetText()
        Label4.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Label4.Text = "THE FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED ABD ABORTED!!!!!"
        Label4.Visible = True
        ' Label5.ResetText()
        Label5.Text = "NO TRANSFER RATE - FILE DOWNLOAD CANCEL and ABORTED"
        Label5.Visible = True
        'Label6.ResetText()
        Label6.Text = "Saved Copy of File Download is : "
        'Label7.ResetText()
        Label7.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Label7.Text = "Download Source File Size is : "
        Label8.ResetText()
        Label8.Text = ""
        'Label10.ResetText()
        Label10.Text = Label10.Text & " was the previous file downloading transfer rate...."

        Return
    End If

    download.Dispose()

    MessageBox.Show("")

    Return

    Kill(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

2. If a BackgroundWokrer is used, then it will be useful as well, but a BackgroundWorker instance can handle various ways of doing this, in formation with a Class that would handle redirects for the form download activity, but that requires more code to display granularity of the activity / event processes, thereby y making the number "1." option as the best solution at hand, maybe not quite for code modularity / modulization,  but for code activity distinction without writing more code and wrapping it a a possible failure point in testing, this is my choice / option implemetation to  !!

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar activity can be very uncertain, in terms of operating and functioning as intended (as you would think it should behave) in the final behavior on a cancellation of a WebClient.CancelAsync() run of the function that this client is assigned to within the application. I do not have knowledge of having a progress bar reset to the minimum value after a download has completed without being cancelled. So, I will offer two snippets of code that I use to play with, as a design basis that seems to be a "simple" starting point of windows form development / ASP.NET development programming, ' BAREBONES ' versions, WITHOUT USING A BACKGROUND WORKER INSTANCE TO PROCESS THE DOWNLOAD ACTIVITY CHANGES.

1. It seems that a "cancellation" of a current download in progress seems to raise some quirky behavior, as a button click does not quite seem to raise the cancel event properly to cause a "stop" and "reset" interruption to the form on the button click of the cancel button, used with CancelAsync() within the button click event. So, I have seen several variant behaviors, depending on what is assigned to the progress bar properties / methods implemented in the code logic of this event.

So, it seems that I have only a simple workaround of using a MessageBox.Show() interruption or a custom form that serves as the same purpose of the message box form.

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    ' THE Kill() IS NOT NECESSARY IF THE MessageBox Show() is IMPLEMENTED AND USED
    'Kill(TextBox2.Text) ' since the Cancel button does not fully stop the download
    ' and clear the prgress bar to reset that to "0", this is used to stop the download
    ' at the root path of the saved file destinatio !!!!n
    download.CancelAsync()
    ProgressBar1.Disposing.ToString()
    ' ProgressBar1.Dispose() ' hides the progress bar here
    ProgressBar1.Update()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    ProgressBar1.Show()
    LastCount = 0

    ' Label4.ResetText()
    Label4.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
    Label4.Text = "THE FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED .. A - N - D .. ALSO ABORTED !!!!!!!"
    Label4.Visible = True
    ' Label5.ResetText()
    Label5.Text = "NO TRANSFER RATE - FILE DOWNLOAD CANCEL and ABORTED"
    Label5.Visible = True
    'Label6.ResetText()
    Label6.Text = "Saved Copy of File Download is : "
    'Label7.ResetText()
    Label7.Text = "Download Source File Size is : "
    Label8.ResetText()
    Label8.Text = ""
    'Label10.ResetText()
    'Label10.Text += Label10.Text & " was the previous file downloading transfer rate...."


    ' trows error if there is not a file in the directory
    ' IO.File.Delete(savedLocation) ' delete the file in the chosen directory, if present

    cmdsave.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
    'Label4.Visible = True ' to alleviate the text that will be shown as the "old"
    'Label5.Visible = True ' values of the cancelled download, so make these not visible
    ' ...... make the labels "invislbe" now, but make them "visible" when the
    ' ...... cmdsae button is clicked, or see if the form load can make them
    ' ...... visbile again  -->>> POST THE CANCELLATION MESSAGE IN
    ' .....  TEXTBOX1 OR LABEL



    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then

        Label4.ResetText()
        Label4.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Label4.Text = ""
        ' Button1.Enabled = False ' DOES NOT WORK HERE !!
        MessageBox.Show("FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED / ABORTED !!")

        Button1.Enabled = False ' DOES W-O-R-K -- GREAT -- HERE !!
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Update()
        ' ProgressBar1.Hide()
        ' ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        'Label4.ResetText()
        Label4.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Label4.Text = "THE FILE DOWNLOAD WAS CANCELLED ABD ABORTED!!!!!"
        Label4.Visible = True
        ' Label5.ResetText()
        Label5.Text = "NO TRANSFER RATE - FILE DOWNLOAD CANCEL and ABORTED"
        Label5.Visible = True
        'Label6.ResetText()
        Label6.Text = "Saved Copy of File Download is : "
        'Label7.ResetText()
        Label7.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        Label7.Text = "Download Source File Size is : "
        Label8.ResetText()
        Label8.Text = ""
        'Label10.ResetText()
        Label10.Text = Label10.Text & " was the previous file downloading transfer rate...."

        Return
    End If

    download.Dispose()

    MessageBox.Show("")

    Return

    Kill(TextBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

2. If a BackgroundWokrer is used, then it will be useful as well, but a BackgroundWorker instance can handle various ways of doing this, in formation with a Class that would handle redirects for the form download activity, but that requires more code to display granularity of the activity / event processes, thereby y making the number "1." option as the best solution at hand, maybe not quite for code modularity / modulization,  but for code activity distinction without writing more code and wrapping it a a possible failure point in testing, this is my choice / option implemetation to  !!

For what it is worth, the typical progress changed procedure that is relative to changing and "zeroing" a progress bar after a download has a normal syntax / semantic expression as noted above, i.e., the answer given by matzone in THIS  POST, and probably the answer that would be given by another expert or knowledgeable .NET programmer regarding this issue. I personally handle the BASIC progress bar ' resetting ', AFTER A SUCCESS and COMPLETION OF A DOWNLOAD procedure to download a file, And IN THE CANCELLATION OF THE CURRENT, ACTIVE DOWNLOAD ( IN PROGRESS ), using DownloadFileAsync of the WEBCLIENT CONTROL as :

Private Sub ...........

```
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage


If e.ProgressPercentage > LastCount Then

    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then

        Label4.ResetText()
        Label4.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite
        Label4.Text = "File Download Is Complete"
        Label7.ResetText()
        Label7.BackColor = Color.Gold
        Label7.Text = "DOWNLOAD STATUS : File was successfully downlaoded !!"

        Label8.ResetText()
        Label8.Text = "LAST DOWNLOADED FILE : " + TextBox2.Text.ToString +
    " with a size of " & GetDownloadSize(TextBox1.Text) & " KB , " +
    "was downloaded on" + DateTime.Now + " from the URL / URI at " +
    TextBox1.Text.ToString + " with a download transfer rate of " +
    "approximately, ( ~ ) " + (e.BytesReceived / (DirectCast(e.UserState, Stopwatch).ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0#)).ToString("#") & " KB. "
```

' do other form functionality / features,  if needed, such as resetting the form's buttons, as shown below :

```
        cmdsave.Enabled = True
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = True
        viewDLfile.Enabled = True
        cmdPaste.Enabled = False
        ProgressBar1.Value = Nothing
        ' TextBox1.Clear() ; seems to throw a 

        Button1.Focus()

        LastCount = 0

        Return
    End If

End If
```

End Sub